# SQL Statement filtering

Tags: sql

I want to create a query that will return all the route_id, that contain both stop variables.

```
|   route_stop_id   |   route_id    |   stop_id |   time (in sec)   |
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
|   1           |   1           |   1       |   3:24pm      |
|   2           |   1           |   2       |   3:26pm      |
|   3           |   1           |   3       |   3:29pm      |
|   4           |   1           |   4       |   4:04pm      |
|   5           |   2           |   1       |   3:03pm      |
|   6           |   3           |   1       |   3:02pm      |
```

If `route_id` has `stop_id = 1` and `stop_id = 2`

```
SELECT route_id FROM route_stop_list WHERE stop_id = 1 and stop_id = 2
```

But the above statement doesn't return anything, because no row can have both a `stop_id` of `1` and a `stop_id` of `2`. But is it possible to write a statement that will return properly?

---

EDIT, more explanation because I think this is kind of confusing.

This is a transportation app.

My application asks the user to enter a starting stop and a ending stop.

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will return all the routes that both stops exists on.

Comment: Do you mean a stop_id of 1 OR a stop_id of 2?
Try replacing AND with OR.

Comment: No I want to return routes that have both stops. Because that means that route is valid.

Comment: "But the above statement doesn't return anything, because no row can have both a stop_id of 1 and a stop_id of 2."
seems to me that this a table design problem. You'll have to add another column named STOP_ID2 and use it for querying purposes as well.

Comment: @Malky.Kid I don't agree, both of those columns would be identical... which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one (edited)

```
SELECT t1.route_id 
FROM route_stop_list t1 join route_stop_list t2 on t1.route_id=t2.route_id
where  t1.stop_id=1 AND t2.stop_id=2
```

explanation

i am joining the 2 tables first(your table with itself). t1 and t2 are just aliases(nicknames) for the tables so that you can refer to them later. this gives us all the possible combinations. the condition for joining is having the same route id. Try running the query without the last line (where clause). Use select * to get all columns. If you still won't understand i'll explain more.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this works! Can you explain the t1 and t2, and what is going on here? Sorry I am new to these kinds of statements.

Comment: Added explanation. Other solutions posted are faster and more appropriate. This one will get you to know joins and another way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks again! It makes a lot more sense when I took out the where... Also, this answer executes faster than the two answers below, that's why I choose this answer.

Comment: ok. just have in mind that probably it works better for small tables but it may be slower in big tables. Nevertheless you should try to understand the other solutions too (ie what the GROUP BY does). You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT route_id 
FROM route_stop_list 
WHERE stop_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY route_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT stop_id)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT route_id FROM route_stop_list
WHERE stop_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY route_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT stop_id) = 2
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb683/1).

The only thing to consider is that you need to match the amount of elements in the `IN` clause with the number in the `HAVING` clause.

Note you don't need to join `N` times where `N` is the amount of routes to find. That is very inefficient.

Finally, bear in mind that you should replace the `HAVING` clause with the following one if there can not be 2 or more same `stop_id` for a given `route_id`:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```